# Node.js addEventListener and other events without browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

The task is to run this script on Node.js without using a browser. The problem is that the code only works in the context of the browser and only in this form.

```
var d1 = {};

function test(data){
    console.log(data);
    d1 = data;
}
addEventListener("test", test, false);

var cv = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");

(function init(e) {
    e.initCustomEvent("test", false, false, ["test1","test2", {test: 'test3'}]);
    dispatchEvent(e)
}(cv));

console.log(d1);
```

if you change the function of init (remove the brackets (...)) then the code will not work correctly.

```
function init(e) {
    e.initCustomEvent("test", false, false, ["test1","test2", {test: 'test3'}]);
    dispatchEvent(e)
}(cv);
```

On the Internet, I found [script](https://notepad.pw/2tztu0v5). The error code does not give out with it, but it works the same as the version of the code without parentheses. What is the problem with this solution? All code was launched [here](https://rextester.com/OHGP55799)

Answer (score 1):

because NodeJS not have DOM and also not have `document` object, you need to make custom event on different way. Check Node docs for that  [Node Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

```js
// get the reference of EventEmitter class of events module
var events = require('events');

//create an object of EventEmitter class by using above reference
var em = new events.EventEmitter();

//Subscribe for FirstEvent
em.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log('First subscriber: ' + data);
});

// Raising FirstEvent
em.emit('test', 'This is my first Node.js event emitter example.');
```